# curl to external apis return 000 http code and empty response when script is run from preStop hook

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

When the pod is terminated, the below script is run as part of preStop hook.
Problem: The curl to google or other apis works fine and returns the value when the script is run inside the pod. But the same script when it is running as part of preStop hook, the curl returns empty and the code returned is 000. Why? Does the pod is disabled from contacting other than localhost apis. The pod is not able to curl to the apis that are part of the cluster. It is only able to curl to it's own api but not others. Anyone has idea how to fix to be able to curl other api's like prometheus, graffana etc.,

testScript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "test curl" > /proc/1/fd/1
echo $(curl -s /dev/null http://google.com) > /proc/1/fd/1
echo $(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://google.com) > /proc/1/fd/1
```

```
kind: Statefulset
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: myapp:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sleep 30 && bash testScript.sh]
```

Result when the script is run inside the pod:

```
test curl
</BODY></HTML>ta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"> <TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY> <H1>301 Moved</H1> The document has moved <A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
301
```

Result when the script is run from the preStop hook

```
test curl

000
```

Comment: Werid, It works on my cluster. I need more information, like your k8s version and what image is your container based on?

Comment: The version is 1.16. I cannot share the image details.